# How to lay a Layout over another, but the first layout is clickable

Tags: android, android-layout, dialog, android-animation

Is there any possibilty to show a layout, if I'm click on a button, which looks like a dialog, but the button, which opened the dialog, is always clickable?
I mean, that I have just one button in my layout and with this I open AND close my "dialog".

The layout, which will open, will have a small animation. Is this possible, if I'm using Dialogs? Or is there any other, better solution?

EDIT:
I think it's not really easy to understand my text, so I try it a little bit easier :D

I just wanna have a button, that open something (dialog, layout,..) with a animation, what look likes a dialog. So the first layout ( where the button is) should be visbile on the side of the new layout/dialog. But it should be also possible, that I click on the button again, to close the dialog/view.

Comment: can you please post your implementation code ?

Comment: I don't have very much, just a dialog :D Because I don't know, what I have to use, to do it like this. I edit my question for better understanding, what i want

Comment: Yes you can make the button as well as the Layout widgets clickable. all you need to do is either, 1. Make a layout instead of dialog, then the button will be clickable. 2. If creating a dialog, then make your dialog as Modal, add  ((Activity) context).getWindow().setFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL, LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL); in your acyivity as the first statement and then make dialog by creating setFlag(FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL)